# Django Admin CSS files are missing

Tags: django, python-3.x

I deployed my django app to pythonanywhere.com
and my admin css not working
http://directdirect.pythonanywhere.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
what do I do?
I use django 2.0
settings.py:

```
 Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_direct/main_app/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_direct/main_app/static'),
    http://directdirect.pythonanywhere.com/static/admin/css/dashboard.css
]
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps indicated by the docs in [howto/static-files in deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#deployment)

Comment: Where is your setting `STATIC_ROOT` pointing to? Can you check your server if the files are where they are supposed to be?

Comment: @Ralf i did $ python manage.py collectstatic
no help

Comment: Can you show `STATIC_ROOT` as well, not just `STATIC_URL` ?

Comment: How have you configured your webserver to serve static files?

Comment: @Ralf don't have static root)

Comment: @Ralf where can i find confguration?

Comment: I posted an answer with more details.

Comment: did you get to solve your problem? Was my answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 7):

Check your `settings.py` file.

```
DEBUG = True    # debug true mod working admin css
DEBUG = False   # debug false mod not working css
```

You can fix it using a proxy server or by running Django with the insecure parameter.

- Use NGINX Proxy Server: [django-with-nginx](https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281)
- Use Insecure Parameter: [run-django-with-insecure-argument](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1022/)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you followed similar instructions to [this page from `help.pythonanywhere.com`](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/).

There it says:

> Go visit your site, it should be live! But it probably **won't** be using your CSS stylesheets, JavaScript and other things that are loaded from static files. To get those set up, check out the page configuring static files with Django.

And [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles) is the link to get those static files up and running.

This should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Just move the admin folder from `static_cdn` to `static` folder